# Excel VBA Type mismatch Run-time error 13

Tags: excel, vba

With this code

```
Sub Rondom()

   Dim arr() As Double
   n = InputBox("enter your number")

   ReDim arr(1 To n) As Double
   For i = 1 To n

   arr(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSInv(Rnd()) * 0.5

   Next i
   cells(3, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(arr, 0.01)

End Sub
```

when I enter 60000 for `n` it works fine. But when I enter 70000, I receive an error saying "type mismatch" and this line

```
cells(3, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(arr, 0.01)
```

is highlighted.

Comment: I'm guessing that the `Percentile` function is expecting a Variant array with 16-bit dimensions and that it's failing trying to do the implicit conversion. (The upper limit of unsigned 16-bits is 65535).

Answer (score 1):

**=PERCENTILE()** can contain at most 8191 data elements.